# Bower Install failing with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, cordova, proxy, bower

I am trying to install an ionic-cordova application and it is showing the following error upon running `bower install`. Removed the proxy settings in npm using `npm config delete proxy` and in bower in `.bowerrc` file. No what is wrong and why this is happening

```
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ionic failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.0s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ydn.db failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.1s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ngCordova failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-mocks failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.8s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-md5 failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-translate failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-translate-loader-partial failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.0s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-aria failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.7s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/moment failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.5s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jszip failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.1s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/oclazyload failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.1s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ckeditor failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-ckeditor failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-messages failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.0s
```

Comment: It may be possible that Bower was down for a moment, can you try again?

Comment: @miparnisari, I have tried many times and even now, log is same :/